# Zip items from two lists that have the same file name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two list: this:

list1(has way more items)

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp']
```

and this:

list2(has way more items)

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AWE\\AWE.shp',  #THIS IS EXTRA
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp']
```

How to ensure that the pairs will match with the corresponding same name on the other list after the zip?

Maybe we match with their previous folder? Like:

```
if list1[0].split('\\')[-2] == list2[0].split('\\')[-2]:
      final = [(f,s) for f,s in zip(list1,list2)]
      final
```

wanted final output :

```
[('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp'),etc..]
```

Comment: Do the two lists have the same length?

Comment: No they don't. it needs also condition for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just group the files with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then output the pairs of length 2 in a separate list.

**Demo:**

```
from os.path import basename
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

f1 = [
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp",
]

f2 = [
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AWE\\AWE.shp",  # THIS IS EXTRA
    "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp",
]

files = defaultdict(list)
for path in f1 + f2:
    filename = path.split('\\')[-1]
    files[filename].append(path)

pairs = [tuple(v) for k, v in files.items() if len(v) == 2]
pprint(pairs)
```

**Output:**

```
[('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp'),
 ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp'),
 ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\prog1\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp')]
```

**Note:** Using [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to extract the filename from Windows paths will only work on Windows. It will simply do nothing on Unix enviorments.

Comment: in `files = defaultdict(list)`. What is the `list` variable?

Comment: @RoadRunner [That is what I get](https://repl.it/repls/UglyOffshoreIteration). The online compiler might be running a different OS though. Hmm

Comment: Tried on my mac in 2 and 3, I get `[]` as well

Comment: @RoadRunner This *rest line doesn't work for python 2.7. Can you write something that would work most of the times. In general it is fine but doesn't work on 2.7. Thanks

Comment: @user10671234 Changed to `filename = path.split('\\')[-1]`. Python2.7 doesn't support `*` tuple unpacking.

Comment: I think it is great.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That would be expected. `basename()` on unix won't know how to deal with Windows paths.

Comment: @RoadRunner On retrospect, it does make sense. +1

Answer (score 0):

This does not address the question directly using zip(), but in case if someone landed here looking for a way to grab files from two lists that have the same file name. This is what I tried in Python:

- given list1, list2
- we want to grab files from list1 that match the name as those in list2

  output_list = [list1 for list1 in list2]

And you can continue and zip(list1, list2) to ensure filenames in two lists are the same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).